# Авторизация в вконтакте

Tags: curl, php, вконтакте, авторизация

Нашел  авторизацию в вк (немного переделал) работает через раз. Что тут не так?

```
$url = 'https://vk.com/'; 
$urlTo = 'login.vk.com?act=login';  
$login = $_POST['log'];  
$pass = $_POST['pass']; 
$post = "role=al_frame&email=$login&pass=$pass";  
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$html = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlTo);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
$html = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
$text = "onLoginDone"; 
if(preg_match("/$text/", $html)){ 
echo 'Удачно авторизовались в Вк'; 
}else{ 
echo "Ошибка"; 
$cookie = ''; 
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в условие с ошибкой код: `echo $html;` и посмотрите, что отдает сервер контакта.

Comment: Пустоту ) ) )